# custom wp_list_categories in single.php

Tags: categories, single

I have created a custom WordPress theme, and I am customizing my post page (single.php).

I would like to display the parent and child categories and sub-child related to the post (wp_list_categories) as below in my posts (single.php) :

```
<div class="categorie">

  <ul class="block">
    <li class="premier_niveau">Category 1</li> > 
    <li class="deuxieme_niveau">category child of 1.1</li> > 
    <li class="troisieme_niveau">category sous-child of 1.1.1 
  </ul>

  <ul class="block"> 
   <li class="premier_niveau">Category 2</li> 
   <li class="deuxieme_niveau">category child of 2.1</li> 
   <li class="deuxieme_niveau">category child of 2.2</li>
  </ul>

  etc.
</div>
```

I am not a coder! But I tried this:

```
<?php
$categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID, array('fields' => 'ids'));
if($categories) {
    $cat_ids = implode(',' , $categories);
    $cats = wp_list_categories('title_li=&style=none&echo=0&include='.$cat_ids);
    echo str_replace('<br />', ' <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> ', $cats);
} 
?>
```

The code above shows me the parent, child and sub-child categories for the item. But it doesn't show me a new ul when a top level category is displayed. It shows me everything in a row as below :

```
Category 1 > category child of 1.1 > category sous-child of 1.1.1 > Category 2 > category child of 2.1 > category child of 2.2
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Can you tell me if I was clear in my explanations ? Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Sorry nobody picked this up! If you want a list of <li>s though, you probably want style=list not style=none.